# Proving the Dirichlet Conditions using the Dirichlet-Dini Criterion

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've been reading Oppenheim's "Signals and Systems" (engineering) textbook and it gives the following "Dirichlet conditions" for pointwise convergence of the Fourier series representation of a function $f$ with period $2\pi$:

1. $f$ is absolutely integrable over its period
2. $f$ is of bounded variation, i.e. $f$ has a finite number of minima and maxima during a single period
3. $f$ has a finite number of finite discontinuities during a single period

From [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657243/dirichlet-conditions-and-the-fundamental-period), the "i.e." part of condition 2 is not true, as there exist functions with bounded variation that have an infinite number of minima or maxima; from the [Wikipedia article on Dirichlet Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions), replacing the above condition 2 with "$f$ has bounded variation" is sufficient.

I've seen the Dirichlet-Dini Criterion on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence): the Fourier series representation of a $2\pi$-periodic, locally integrable function $f$ converges at $x_0$ to $l$ if:
$$ \int_0^\pi \left| \frac{f(x_0 + t) + f(x_0 - t)}{2} - l \right| \frac{dt}{t} < \infty $$

My intuition is that this criterion is a generalization of the above Dirichlet conditions. Is it possible to prove the above Dirichlet conditions (either the finite extrema or bounded variation case) using the Dirichlet-Dini criterion? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the following, where $S_N^f(\theta)$ is the Fourier series truncated to the terms $1,\sin(n\theta),\cos(n\theta)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots,N$.
$$
      S_{N}^f(\theta)-L=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}D_N(\theta')\left[\frac{f(\theta+\theta')+f(\theta-\theta')}{2}-L\right]d\theta.
$$
The Dirichlet-Dini condition is formulated to make sure that the above tends to $0$ as $N\rightarrow 0$, which gives convergence of the Fourier series at $\theta$ to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $f$. The Dirichlet kernel is
$$
        \sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{in\phi}=\frac{\sin\left[\frac{1}{2}(2N+1)\phi\right]}{\sin\left[\frac{1}{2}\phi\right]}
$$